# Android sdkmanager not found issue in ubuntu 22.04 based linux container

Tags: android, flutter, lxc, proxmox

I am trying to install flutter on ubuntu 22.04 based linux container (on proxmox server).

```
sdkmanager --version
```

shows 7.0

```
flutter doctor
```

shows message "Flutter requires Android SDK 29 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3"

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

shows message that Android sdkmanager not found.  Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this.

```
sdkmanager --update
```

shows no updates available.

```
sdkmanager --list
```

shows
Installed packages:=====================] 100% Computing updates...
Path                 | Version | Description                             | Location
-------              | ------- | -------                                 | -------
build-tools;28.0.3   | 28.0.3  | PLACEHOLDER                             | build-tools/28.0.3
cmdline-tools;latest | 7.0     | Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) | cmdline-tools/latest
platform-tools       | 33.0.2  | PLACEHOLDER                             | platform-tools

I found many solutions involving use of GUI on windows and Linux. Considering I have access to terminal and no GUI available, how do I resolve this issue

[image: Snapshot of terminal]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to enable graphical apps in your LXC container and run Android Studio inside LXC. The steps below will create a new LXC container with full X11 enabled (works with Wayland on the host too). Tested successfully on recent versions of Ubuntu (no audio support though).

**1.** Copy the following text into a new file `/tmp/lxc_x11.profile`:

```
config:
  environment.DISPLAY: :0
  environment.PULSE_SERVER: unix:/home/ubuntu/pulse-native
  #nvidia.driver.capabilities: all
  #nvidia.runtime: "true"
  user.user-data: |
    #cloud-config
    runcmd:
      - 'sed -i "s/; enable-shm = yes/enable-shm = no/g" /etc/pulse/client.conf'
    packages:
      - x11-apps
      - mesa-utils
      - pulseaudio
description: GUI LXD profile
devices:
  PASocket1:
    bind: container
    connect: unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native
    listen: unix:/home/ubuntu/pulse-native
    security.gid: "1000"
    security.uid: "1000"
    uid: "1000"
    gid: "1000"
    mode: "0777"
    type: proxy
  X0:
    bind: container
    connect: unix:@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
    listen: unix:@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
    security.gid: "1000"
    security.uid: "1000"
    type: proxy
  mygpu:
    type: gpu
name: x11
used_by: []
```

**2.** Set up the new container:

```
VMNAME=name-of-new-container
lxc launch ubuntu:22.04 $VMNAME
lxc profile create x11 2>@1 |grep -v 'The profile already exists'  # needed once on host
cat /tmp/lxc_x11.profile |lxc profile edit x11  # needed once on host
lxc profile assign $VMNAME default,x11  # note--this changes sshd hostkey
lxc exec $VMNAME -- apt update
lxc exec $VMNAME -- sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractivee apt install -y x11-apps mesa-utils libxi6
lxc restart $VMNAME
lxc exec $VMNAME -- sudo --user ubuntu glxgears
```